# Free fall with resistance: solution to the ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'm having trouble solving this ODE:

> $$\ddot x = \mu \dot x^2 - g,  \space \space x(0)=x_0$$

This is the ODE that determines the equation of motion of an object with air resistance. $\mu$ is a positive constant. This is what I've done:

Let $\dot x = v$ we have $v(0)  = 0$ by assumption and the equation becomes:

$$\dot v = \mu v^2 - g$$

This is a Riccati differential equation. Recall that a Riccati differential equation has the form

$$\dot x = h(t) + f(t) x + g(t)x^2$$

In our case is $h(t) = -g$, $f(t) = 0$ and $g(t) = \mu$

To solve this kind of differential equations one has to guess a solution, which in this case I found be:

$$v_p(t) = \sqrt{g \over \mu}$$

$\implies y = {1 \over {v- \sqrt{g \over n}}}$ $\implies y(0) = \sqrt{n\over g}$ to find the solution $v(t)$ one has to solve the following differential equation:

$$\dot y = -(f(t) + 2v_pg(t))y-g(t)$$

This is what I've done:

\begin{align}
\dot y & = -(f(t) + 2v_pg(t))y-g(t) \\
& \dot y = -2 \sqrt{g\mu }\space y - \mu \space 
& (1)
\end{align}

Now this is a linear inhomogeneous differential equation an the solution is given by the sum of the homogeneous solution $y_h(t)$ with the particular solution $y_p (t)$ The homogeneous solution comes from:

$$\dot y = -2 \sqrt{g\mu }\space y \implies y_h = y(0) e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }}$$

for the particular solution $y_p(t)$ is a little bit more complicated then to find it I substituted

$$y_p(t) = y(0)(t)e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} = C_1 (t)e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }}$$

in the equation (1). This is what I get:

\begin{align}
 y_p(t)& =C_1(t)' e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} -2 \sqrt{g\mu }C_1(t)e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} = -2 \sqrt{g\mu }C_1(t)e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} - \mu 
\end{align} 
\begin{align}
\iff C_1(t)' e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} & = -\mu
\end{align}

$$ \iff C_1(t) = {-\mu \over {2 \sqrt{g\mu }}}e^{2 \sqrt{g\mu }}$$

summarizing we have

$$y(t) = {1 \over v - \sqrt {g \over n}} = C_1(t)e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} + y_h(t)= {-\mu \over {2 \sqrt{g\mu }}}e^{2 \sqrt{g\mu }}e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} + y(0) e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }} $$

$$= {-\mu \over {2 \sqrt{g\mu }}} + y(0) e^{-2 \sqrt{g\mu }}$$

from here I tried to solve $y = {1 \over {v- \sqrt{g \over n}}}$ with respect to $v$ and then solve the last ODE $v = \dot x$ but I think that something has gone wrong.

Is there an alternative way to solve the original ODE?  Is the method I've used the only one?

Comment: Note that you can *choose* the initial velocity to be $0$, but it does not necessarily have to be. If your line $\dot{x}(0)=\dot{x}_0=0$ is meant as a justification, it is wrong like saying $f(0)=c\Rightarrow f'(0)=\frac{d}{dt}c=0.$ As your ODE is second order, you are free to choose both $x(0)=x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0)=v_0$.

Comment: Your are right, sorry, I'll edit it right away. However, the initial condition is v(0) = 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you asked for *methods* I decided to post an alternative. Here we use the trick of ***eliminating the inhomogeneity***.

First, consider only the equation for $v(t)=\dot{x}(t)$,

$$\dot{v}=\mu v^2-g.$$ The inhomogeneity $-g$ prevents us from simple integration of the ODE, so let's make it disappear by defining $w(t)=v(t)-\gamma$, which leads to

$$\dot{w}=\mu w^2+2\mu\gamma w+\mu\gamma^2-g.$$ We see that the choice $\gamma=\sqrt{g/\mu}$ kills the constant term, leadig to the ***homogenous*** equation for $w$:
$$\frac{dw}{dt}=\mu w^2+2\sqrt{\mu g}w,$$ which now can directly be integrated:

$$\int_{w_0}^{w(t)} \frac{dw}{\mu w^2+2\sqrt{\mu g}w}=\int_0 ^t dt.$$ This can be solved using $\int dt/(at^2+bt)=-(2/b)\text{artanh} (2at/b+1)$ (for $b>0$) which gives

$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\mu g}}\text{artanh}\left( \mu w+1 \right)-C=t$$ with some integration constant $C$. We can solve this for $w$ and obtain
$$w(t)=\sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}\left( \tanh[-\sqrt{\mu g}(t+C)]-1 \right).$$ Transforming back to our original function $v$ gives
$$v(t)=w(t)+\gamma=\sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}} \tanh[-\sqrt{\mu g}(t+C)],$$ and from the initial condition $v(0)=0$ it follows that $C=0$.

Now you can integrate $v=\dot{x}$ to get the position solution using that $\int dt \tanh(t)=\ln (\cosh x)$ arriving at

> $$x(t)=x_0-\frac{1}{\mu}\ln\left[ \cosh(-\sqrt{\mu g}t) \right],$$

where the integration constant has been chosen such that $x(0)=x_0$.

Comment: +1 I like this approach, as it is more succinct. I will check my method to see how the two answers can be resolved.

Comment: In particular, one does not have to guess a solution to the differential equation, as the original poster suggested. It can be integrated as shown here.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions (thank you Chinny84 too ;-)). I have a problem with your substitution: you say let $w(t)=v(t)-\gamma$ this leads to $w^2(t) = v(t)^2 -2\gamma v(t) + \gamma ^2$ which solved with respect to $v(t)^2$ leads $\dot v = \dot w = \mu (w(t)^2 + 2\gamma v(t) -\gamma ^2) -g= \mu w(t)^2 + 2\gamma \mu v(t) - \mu \gamma ^2 -g$ this equation is now linear inhomogeneous, also with the choice of $\gamma = - \sqrt{g \over \mu}$ not homogeneous as you said, isn't it?

Comment: @Ale You should *not* substitute $v^2\to w^2+2\gamma v-\gamma^2$ (because then you still have a $v$ left) but use the proper substitution $v^2 \to (w+\gamma)^2$ (i.e. substitute *before* squaring) which will lead you to the second equation of my answer.

Comment: I have a little question: when you evaluate $\int_{w_0}^{w(t)} \frac{dw}{\mu w^2+2\sqrt{\mu g}w}$ you get as result: $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\mu g}}\text{artanh}\left( \mu w+1 \right)-C=t$. My question is: since we have $v(0) = 0 \implies w(0) = \gamma = \sqrt{g\over \mu}$ right? Now when you evaluate the integral you should get $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\mu g}}\text{artanh}\left( \mu w(t)+1 \right) - \frac{-1}{\sqrt{\mu g}}\text{artanh}\left( \mu w(0)+1 \right)-C=t$ or is the second therm of the integral contained in the constant C?

Comment: @Ale Your last assumtion is right, I have put all constants into one $C$ to make life easier. You just need to remember that this $C$ determines the initial condition $w_0$ (or $v_0$).

Comment: @Ale Just to be precise, note that if $F$ is the antiderivative function, your equation after integrating is $F(w(t))-F(w_0)=t-t_0$, so you have *two* free constants, the starting time $t_0$ and your initial condition $w_0$. According to your question, $t_0=0$ is already chosen, so in the equation of your last comment, you should *not* have *two* constants, your $C$ corresponds to the already chosen $t_0$.

Comment: However thank you for showing me this method to eleminate the inhomogeneity, this is really powerful! Also because with my method I surely made some mistakes. I'm going to try your approach with other inhomogeneous differential equation, do you suggest it to me?

Comment: @Ale I can't tell how often the method will work, but it's always a good idea to remember new tricks and keep them in your treasure chest for the rest of your life :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact
$$
\ddot{x} = \dot{x}\frac{d}{dx}\dot{x} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\dot{x}^{2}}{2}
$$
then the equation becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{v^{2}}{2} = \mu v^{2} - g
$$
Then you can solve directly to get 
$$
v^{2}\mathrm{e}^{-2\mu x} = \int 2g \mathrm{e}^{-2\mu x} dx + C_{1} = -\frac{g}{\mu}\mathrm{e}^{-2\mu x} + C_{1}
$$
if $\dot{x}(0)=x(0)=0$ then 
$$
C_{1} = \frac{g}{\mu}
$$
Hence
$$
v =\sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{2\mu x} - 1} 
$$
then 
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{2\mu x} - 1} 
$$
this leads
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{2\mu x} - 1} }dx = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}t + C_{1}
$$
solving the right hand side yields
$$
\frac{1}{\mu}\arctan{\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{2\mu x} - 1} } = \sqrt{\frac{g}{\mu}}t + C_{1},\\
\sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{2\mu x} - 1}  = \tan{\left(\sqrt{\mu g}t + C_{2}\right)}
$$
and then finally
$$
x(t) = \frac{1}{\mu}\ln{\left[\sec{\left(\sqrt{\mu g}t + C_{2}\right)}\right]}
$$

Check it out if it works out correctly. I did this without pen and paper..but the method holds (I think).

Comment: How is $\ddot{x} = \dot{x}\frac{d}{dx}\dot{x}$? First I guess you mean $\ddot{x} = \dot{x}\frac{d}{dt}\dot{x}$, but still I think it's wrong.

Comment: @flonk $\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dt}$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: I didn't find the mistake yet, but your solution $x(t)$ is periodic in time, whereas the particle should fall down monotonously $\to-\infty$.

Comment: @flonk monotonically :) monotonous means boring

Comment: @Jonathan Oh thanks. However, aren't monotonic functions quite boring?